# Get elements of one column with certain values of another column with DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia

Having a dataframe `df` with columns `:a` and `:b`, how can I get all elements in column `:a` that are in a row with e.g. `b = 0.5`?
Can this be done with `DataFrames` alone or is a meta package needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[df.b .== 5, :]
```

Example

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=11:17, b=vcat([5,5],1:5))
7×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 11    │ 5     │
│ 2   │ 12    │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 13    │ 1     │
│ 4   │ 14    │ 2     │
│ 5   │ 15    │ 3     │
│ 6   │ 16    │ 4     │
│ 7   │ 17    │ 5     │

julia> df[df.b .== 5, :]
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 11    │ 5     │
│ 2   │ 12    │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 17    │ 5     │
```

If you want just the column `a`:

```
julia> df[df.b .== 5, :].a
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 12
 17
```

Yet another option is to use `filter` with a lambda function (this is slightly faster and uses less memory):

```
julia> filter(row -> row[:b] == 5, df)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 11    │ 5     │
│ 2   │ 12    │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 17    │ 5     │
```

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please clarify the comment about ``filter`` being slightly faster? In a related answer, Bogumił Kamiński stated something a bit different (perhaps the context is different): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220143/julia-dataframe-select-rows-based-values-of-one-column-belonging-to-a-set

Comment: My answer is without external packages. There are many ways to do the same thing in any language.